# Is there any way to hide Play/Pause buttons in the AVPictureInPictureController?

Tags: ios

I am using AVPictureInPictureController in my app, but I want to hide the play/pause button and the progress bar. Some app Has achieved this effect.

Comment: "Some app Has achieved this effect." What app?

Comment: This one,   https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/%E6%8E%A7%E6%97%B6-%E7%9C%9F%E6%AD%A3%E7%9A%84%E6%82%AC%E6%B5%AE%E6%97%B6%E9%92%9F/id1536264654